Platform Event is not listening in Salesforce for Standard Composite API Request
I am validating the external inbound API call using Postman. The external application is publishing the Salesforce standard Composite API, which has only one task to fire the platform event.
I am able to publish the Composite API from post(i.e. getting OPERATION_ENQUEUED message) but the debug log is not showing any entry. I set the debug log for automation user and the integration user and has all the required permission for the platform event.
Do I follow any additional steps to see the debug logs or is it because of Composite API , I am not able to see the logs.  Any help ?
Endpoint - https://{{base_url}}/services/data/v58.0/composite/
Body -
 {
  "allOrNone": true,
  "compositeRequest": [
    {
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/Event_Update__e",
      "referenceId": "event1",
      "body": {
      "Event_Type__c": "",
      "Event_Body__c" : "{\"incentive\":{\"event_type\":\"Open\",\"code\":\"{{code}}\",\"channel\":\"Phone\","product_code\":\"97\"}"
      "Source__c" : "customer"
      }
    }
  ]
}


Have you subscribed to platform event via flows or apex trigger?if you have not there wont be anything showed in debug logs of automation user

I subscribed the platform event via trigger and the integration user profile has permission to create the platform event.

someone configured 'PlatformEventSubscriberConfigs' to run the platform event as another user other than automated user. its resolved now.
